# com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl cannot be cast to com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl

Tags: java, casting, liferay

I tried to cast Action response like this:

```
 private void mappingMethod(ActionResponse response) {

        ActionResponseImpl actionResponseImpl = (ActionResponseImpl)response;
...}
```

In debugging on "Expression Evaluation" window I can see the type of "responce" is ActionResponseImpl, and cast does not cause exception. But on runtime I have this exeption:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl cannot be cast to com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl

Please tell me what is the problem.

P.S.: In PortalImpl class, the copyRequestParameters method has same string, but here it's working....

Comment: -1: Can't make out from the question what exactly you want? Also what does this suppose to mean "the copyRequestParameters method has same string, but here it's working...."? Can you also provide the Liferay version you are working on?

Answer (score 3):

It would do you good if you refrained from using classes from `portal-impl.jar` in your custom plugin portlet.

`ActionResponseImpl` is a class in the `portal-impl.jar`. So if you can give a use-case as to why you are planning to use this class, then we can suggest alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You have ActionResponseImpl twice on the classpath - what jars from Liferay did you include in your project? As Prakash mentions, it's portal-impl.jar, which you *can not have* in a plugin.

What the ClassCastException wants to tell you is that your class extends one implementation of ActionResponseImpl, but the runtime environments expects it to be another implementation - they might be identical, but as they are loaded from two different sources, the classloader cannot refer one to another superclass than it extends.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue, when I call a method using Ajax from XHTML page. I modified my method to return simple string and removed the code that tries to modify the actionResponseImpl and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors are produced by different classloaders. A class is identified by their fully qualified class name AND its Classloader. So if you embedd portal-impl in your portlet; the action is going to receive an ActionResponseImpl instance from the portal classloader and is trying to cast this one to a class of your portlet class loader .

see more: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue018.html